# Seeding DB with Entity Framework 6.1.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, seeding

I'm new to web dev in general and new to .Net. As such I started following this tutorial (using vs 2015, MVC 5, EF 6.1.3): http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

and applying it to a test app I wanted to make for fleet management. I created my seeding class, and am now at the configuration part where I want to tell EF to use the initializer class. My web.config file looks like this, not like the one in the tutorial (which was made using EF 6.1.0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

From what I understand, for flexibility reasons, the configuration is now done in Startup.cs, but I cannot find info on how to use the DbContext I created and the Initialize class that I also created for seeding. Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: It looks like you're mixing an matching incompatible versions of components. If you're utilizing .NET Core, then I think you'll also need EF Core. However, bear in mind that if you're just starting out and you want to do real world applications, you should focus for now on ASP.NET 4.5, MVC 5 and EF 6. All the Core products are still in infancy, and remain feature-incomplete and not quite ready for prime-time. You can still play around with, and in fact, you probably *should*, but for anything destined for production, you should stick the previous gen.

Comment: Thx. Figured it out yesterday after posting. You are right, thx for confirmation!